# Converting java.util.Date to java.sql.Date resulting in date changes

Tags: java, sql, date

I was having some problem when trying to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date. My date parameter passed in was originally a string in this format: 2019-01-31. Then I am trying to convert it to java.util.date using this code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date =  formatter.parse(this._dDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In my SQL statement, I am trying to convert it to java.sql.Date:

```
buffer.append("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE LAST_LOGIN_DT < ");
buffer.append("TO_DATE('" + new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()) + "','YYYY-MM-DD') ");
```

However, when I printed out the buffer in string, I realized that the date is changed. For instance, the data string I passed in is 2018-01-01, but in the SQL statement it became 2017-12-31. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The case of the format matters.

Comment: You wanted `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.  But don't do this.  Go straight from your `String` to your `java.sql.Date`.  It will save you a great deal of stress.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Sorry but you mean just change the SQL to "TO_DATE('" + new java.sql.Date(date) + "','yyyy-MM-dd') " and remove the date conversion code instead?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.  Since `_dDate` contains a `String` in the right format, you could just write `buffer.append("TO_DATE('" + new java.sql.Date(_dDate)) + "','YYYY-MM-DD') ");`.  Your alternative is just to change `YYYY-MM-DD` to `yyyy-MM-dd` in the `SimpleDateFormat` (not in the SQL).

Comment: I also recommend using `PreparedStatement` instead of building your SQL via string concatenation.  For all sorts of reasons.

Comment: Just use `java.sql.Date.valueOf(this._dDate)` with `yyyy-MM-dd` format for conversion directly.

Comment: But the _dDate is in String format, if I changed to new java.sql.Date(_dDate), it is highlighted as syntax error

Comment: Another option is [JDBC escape syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-jdbc-sql-escape-syntax-explain) `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE LAST_LOGIN_DT < {d '2018-01-01'}`

Comment: @LHCHIN So you mean like this: "TO_DATE('" + java.sql.Date.valueOf(this._dDate)) + "','yyyy-MM-dd') " ?

Comment: @hyperfkcb I think both `TO_DATE('" + java.sql.Date.valueOf(this._dDate)) + "','yyyy-MM-dd')` and `TO_DATE('" + java.sql.Date.valueOf(this._dDate)) + "','YYYY-MM-DD')` should work. The key is the format of `this._dDate` must be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @LHCHIN I see I see so that means I need to change the date format in date conversion part to yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: @hyperfkcb YES, you got it! But the better way is directly using `java.sql.Date.valueOf(this._dDate)` without converting `util.Date` to `sql.Date`.

Comment: did you try doing a System.out on the converted java.util.Date and saw the result. It will be something like Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 UTC 2017 . That is what goes to sql.Date as you "converted the date without any timezone info, it assumed the default time zome)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use any of the two `Date` classes. They are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead just use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Specifically `select * from table1 where last_login_dt < ?;` and `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-31"));`.

Comment: * That should have been `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(1, LocalDate.parse("2019-01-31"));`.(the `setObject` method takes two arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at following example first:

```
String date = "2018-01-01";

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
System.out.println(sdf1.parse(date));
System.out.println(sdf1.parse(date).getYear());
System.out.println(sdf1.parse(date).getMonth());
System.out.println(sdf1.parse(date).getDay());

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf2.parse(date));
System.out.println(sdf2.parse(date).getYear());
System.out.println(sdf2.parse(date).getMonth());
System.out.println(sdf2.parse(date).getDay());
```

Console output:

> Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 CST 2017
>   117
>   11
>   0
>   Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2018
>   118
>   0
>   1

Now I think you have already noticed the difference!
Quoted from [Class SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> **Y** means **Week year** and **D** means **Day in year**.
>   **y** means **Year** and **d** means **Day in month**.

*yyyy* and *YYYY* both represent a year but *yyyy* represents the calendar year while *YYYY* represents the year of the week. And, *dd* represents the calendar day while *DD* represents the day of the month. Therefore, there are 2 ways to fix your issue:

**Method 1**
Change the format for `SimpleDateFormat` from *YYYY-MM-DD* to *yyyy-MM-dd* if you still want to convert `this._dDate` to `java.util.Date` then `java.sql.Date`, but I strongly recommend you don't do this.

**Method 2**
The better way is directly using `java.sql.Date.valueOf(this._dDate)` and the format of `this._dDate` is supposed to be *yyyy-MM-dd*.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear explanation! Let me test it and get back to you :)

Comment: @hyperfkcb You're welcome! But why you unaccepted and unupvoted for my answer? Does not it work for you?